# Rendering multiple children smart contracts

Tags: solidity, web3js, react

Hello guys so im making a dapp where there is a parent contract and there is a function that creates new smart contract.When i will be building the front end is it possible to render multiple smart contracts on one page with a solidity func that returns the smart contracts. So i need cards of smart contract that would be on one page and they would have variables and functions. Is it possible to make it or do i need a func in solidity that returns those smart contract with variables,function and stuff?

So here is an example of a sc.

> 

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.11;



 contract CarFactory {

     Car[] deployedCars;

   function createCar(uint _seats,uint _doors,uint _wheels,string memory 
       _name) public {
   Car newCar=new Car(this,_seats,_doors,_wheels,_name);
   deployedCars.push(newCar);  
 }

  function getDeployedCars() public view returns (Car[] memory) {
    return deployedCars;
  }

 
  }


  contract Car {

  CarFactory  factory;

   bool made;
   string name;
   uint wheels;
   uint doors;
   uint seats;

 constructor(CarFactory  _factory,uint _seats,uint _doors,uint 
 _wheels,string memory _name) {
   factory=_factory;
   name=_name;
   wheels=_wheels;
   doors=_doors;
   seats=_seats;
 }

  function makeTrue() public {
   made=true;
 }

 }
```

In this contract i create cars so i would like to display cards(on one page) and in those cards i would like to display the car name,and the num of wheels,seats,doors he has and also the function makeTrue(). Is the function getDeployedCars() + functions in the Car sc that return the variables enough to do that or i need to create a different function?

Comment: In most cases the answer will be yes, it should be possible, but we can't provide any details because you haven't supplied any code we can check.

Comment: Ok i added an example